# Partitioning a smooth manifold into geodesically convex sets

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, smooth-manifolds, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a connected and compact $d$-dimensional smooth manifold; where $d$ is a positive integer.  Does *(or rather, when does)* there exist a metric $\rho$ on $X$ generating $X$'s topology and a countable number of sets $\{X_n\}_{n}$ such that

- $\bigcup_n\,X_n = X$,
- Each $X_n$ is $\rho$-geodesically convex,
- Each $X_n$ is contractable,
- $\mu(X_n\cap X_m)=0$ whenever $n\neq m$ *(almost disjoint)*,
- There is a $d$-dimensional Ahfors regular measure on $(X,\rho)$ such that
  $$
  n\neq m \Rightarrow \rho(X_n\cap X_m)=0.
  $$

**Comment:** *Ideally, I would like $\{X_n\}_n$ to be a finite set; but I'm open to countably infinite also..*

---

**Definition**:

- A measure $\mu$ is Ahfors regular if there are $q,c,C>0$ such that
  $$
  c\,r^q \le \mu(Ball_{\rho}(x,r)) \le C\,r^q.
  $$

Comment: Could you clarify the question a bit? As it stands, couldn't you just Whitney embed $M \to \mathbf{R}^{2d}$, take the induced Riemannian metric for $\rho$, the volume measure for $\mu$, and take $\{ M \}$ as a partition?

Comment: @LeoMoos I modified the question to simplify the required condition greatly.

Comment: Did you mean $\mu(X_n\cap X_m)=0$?

Comment: @PierrePC Do you have a reference for this?  Also there must be some limitation (ie cases where this doesn't work) by Anton's comment below.

Comment: @PierrePC no, it is not true, see the second part of my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose a triangulation of $X$.
Let us equip $X$ with a length metric such that each simplex is standard.
We may think that $X$ subcomplex of a standard simplex $S$ of large dimension.

Since each face of $S$ is convex; it follows that each simplex is a convex set in $X$.
Therefore the covering of $X$ by the simplexes of maximal dimension meets your requirement.

Let me also mention that from [our result](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.15189) with Alexander Lytchak it follows that there is no finite covering for generic Riemannian metric on $X$.
Namely, for any covering $\{X_i\}$ of $X$, we have that $X_i\cap X_j$ has nonempty interior for some $i\ne j$;
hence $\mu(X_i\cap X_j)>0$.

Comment: Would you mind expanding on how your result implies that a generic metric on $X$ cannot satisfy the requirements? I am struggling to find where the extremal points come into play. Also, are your generic Riemannian metrics smooth? (I am not sure if the $\mathcal C^2$ regularity refers only to the topology.)

Comment: I'm having trouble with the second part of the solution, namely: Let us equip X with a length metric such that each simplex is isometric to the right-angled spherical simplex.  Could iask you to elaborate since I'm not familiar with these terms/constructions.

Comment: @PierrePC I have updated my answer.

Comment: @AIM I have updated my answer.  (cannot use two names in one comment)

Comment: @AntonPetrunin Thanks a lot, let me ask, why do you use a spherical simplex?  This I can't see (why not a typical Euclidean simplex?)

Comment: @AIM very good question --- there is no reason :) This construction is due to Berestovskii, he proved that with spherical metric it is CAT(1) space, so I took his construction without changing and thinking. I will change it now.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin (oh ok cool, I was worried it was something very elementary I was missing).  Also, if its not too much trouble, I would love to read the paper of Berestovskii; if you have a link I would be very greatful :)

Comment: @AIM The statement easily follows from Gromov's flag test for CAT(1) spaces. The original paper of Berestovskii is in Russian: В. Н. Берестовский. «Задача Борсука о метризации полиэдра». Докл. АН СССР 268.2 (1983), 273—277.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin But just one thing, in this construction, is $\cup_n \, X_n$ homotopic to X or does it only simply cover it in some larger ambient space?

Comment: @AIM I did not get your last question --- $\bigcup_n X_n=X$.

Comment: Oh I maybe misunderstood understood, I way visualizing the shadow of the complex triangulating X (with X embedded in an ambient space).  Never-ending, it is clear now; I guess you pullback the length metric on the complex triangulating X via the homeomorphism between the two no?

Comment: Also here $\mu$ is the d-dimensional Hausdorff measure (restricted to Borel sets)?

Comment: @AIM yes, μ might be the d-dimensional Hausdorff measure or any Ahfors regular measure.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin Last question, sorry for so many, but why do we need to pass to the barycentric subdivision?

Comment: @AIM Otherwise proving that each simplex is convex will be harder. I do not see a proof now, but I am sure it is true.

Comment: @AIM I removed barycentric subdivision.